# Determining ServiceType of a Service in Windows?

Tags: windows-services

Are there any utilities or features built into Windows to determine the [ServiceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfdtdw0e(v=vs.110).aspx) for services installed on the machine?

Comment: Of course: QueryServiceConfig, sc.exe, and the Services administrative tool, for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET, have a look at the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  I've used it to start and stop my service, but you can apparently use it to retrieve all of the services on the local machine, including the device driver services.  Here's an example based on MSDN:

```
var services = new List<ServiceController>();

// Get all the device driver services.
services.AddRange(ServiceController.GetDevices());

// Get all the non-device driver services.
services.AddRange(ServiceController.GetServices());

int numAdapter = 0,
    numFileSystem = 0, 
    numInteractive = 0,
    numKernel = 0, 
    numRecognizer = 0,
    numWin32Own = 0,
    numWin32Share = 0;

// Iterate over the list to determine the number of each `ServiceType`.
foreach (var service in services)
{
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.Adapter) != 0)
    {
        numAdapter++;
    } 
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.FileSystemDriver) != 0)
    {
        numFileSystem++;
    }
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.InteractiveProcess != 0)
    {
        numInteractive++;
    }
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.KernelDriver) != 0)
    {
        numKernel++;
    } 
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.RecognizerDriver) != 0)
    {
        numRecognizer++;
    }
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.Win32OwnProcess) != 0)
    {
        numWin32Own++;
    }
    if ((service.ServiceType & ServiceType.Win32ShareProcess) != 0)
    {
        numWin32Share++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output? See related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981412/why-doesnt-get-service-show-services-with-the-kerneldriver-servicetype)