# Why doesn't Get-Service show services with the KernelDriver ServiceType?

Tags: powershell, service, windows-services

I was playing around with the [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7.3) to list certain types of services. Then I ran into the service shown as `RDPDR`:

```
# Get-Service RDPDR | Select-Object *

UserName            :
Description         : Remote Desktop Device Redirector Driver
DelayedAutoStart    : False
BinaryPathName      : System32\drivers\rdpdr.sys
StartupType         : Manual
Name                : RDPDR
RequiredServices    : {RDBSS}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : False
DisplayName         : Remote Desktop Device Redirector Driver
DependentServices   : {UmRdpService}
MachineName         : .
ServiceName         : RDPDR
ServicesDependedOn  : {RDBSS}
StartType           : Manual
ServiceHandle       : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeServiceHandle
Status              : Stopped
ServiceType         : KernelDriver
Site                :
Container           :
```

However, I discovered that this is not listed when not giving the exact name, such as:

```
# Not from here:
# Get-Service | Select Status, StartType, Name, DisplayName | Sort-Object -Property Name |ft -AutoSize


# Neither here:
# Get-Service  | Select Status, Name, ServiceType | Sort-Object -Property Name |ft -AutoSize
```

So I was expecting to be able to list them with:

```
# Gives weird errors, and no results
# Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.ServiceType -eq "KernelDriver"}

Get-Service: Service 'McpManagementService (McpManagementService)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
Get-Service: Service 'NPSMSvc_1cde02 (NPSMSvc_1cde02)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
Get-Service: Service 'WebManagementUser_1cde02 (WebManagementUser_1cde02)' cannot be queried due to the following error:
```

**Q: How can I list all the Services where the [`ServiceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicetype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) is `KernelDriver`?**

---

**UPDATE:**

There are (at least) 3 related bugs filed in powershell repo.

1. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20188
2. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19373
3. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10371

Related

- [Determining ServiceType of a Service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493445/determining-servicetype-of-a-service-in-windows)

Comment: If you open Services.msc, does it also fail to read the description for these services as well, mine does for McpManagementService, kinda seems like a Windows bug, or maybe some higher level of security as they don't want you getting details from those services maybe.

Comment: Yep, same here. But now I can at least see the error code "15100" which is described as: `ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: @KG-DROID Good question.  My service.msc does open and lists McpManagementService.  However, the Description text contains "<Failed to Read Description. Error Code: 15100>"    It doesn't error.  But PS fails... and only when I pipe it through | Where-Object.

Comment: Seems there's a *lot* of services that don't come back unless you call for them by name with `Get-Service`. CIM Instances though... I don't know if this is every single KernelDriver service, but it sure looks like it could be: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName cim_service -Filter "CreationClassName = 'Win32_SystemDriver'"|get-service|where{$_.ServiceType -eq 'KernelDriver'}`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That command only returns: `Get-CimInstance: Generic failure`...